# How make authentication in server components Next js 13 if I use local storage to preserve jwt?

Tags: authentication, jwt, local-storage, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I use this hook wrapped as provider in my main layout.tsx  to authenticate use on visiting page.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"; 

export function useAuthProfile() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getProfile() {
      try {
        const authToken = localStorage.getItem("x-auth-token");

        if (!authToken) {
          return router.push("/login");
          
        }

        const response = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/user`,
          {
            headers: {
              "x-auth-token": authToken,
            },
          }
        );

        setProfile(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
        return router.push("/login");
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    getProfile();
  }, [router]);

  return { profile, loading, error };
}
```

but I want to authenticate user in my server components also again if they visit them, for example /channels , because I want to get consistency which channels I get on client and on server if user channels were changed before.

I thought that I can save in redux storage my token on first user visit. Then I can use this token not from local storage but rather from redux so I can perform auth in server components . So this way I will need to use client side only once to store token. But is it good approach or not?

Good to know I have redux toolkit so you can use it in your code examples.